# Destructuring array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Does postgres allow array destructuring, e.g:

```
-- Assuming all table rows have arrays of {int, int}
SELECT x[1], x[2] from table x; -- this works

-- How to do this, to get same results as above ?
SELECT X, Y from table AS {X, Y} -- ??
SELECT X, Y from table AS ARRAY[X, Y] -- ??
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what you mean by *destructuring*.

Comment: `SELECT unnest(x), unnest(y) FROM x;` ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Your first line of code is correct. What do you want to say with the last two? Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Do you mean `select x[1] as x, x[2] as y from the_table...`

Comment: Basically I want the same statement but instead of `x[1], x[2]` I want to refer to X, Y in select

Comment: @nehz: then doesn't the suggestion by a_horse_with_no_name does what you want?